# How to force laravel to output localhost:3000 in {{ url('/') }} for browsersync to work?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, browser-sync

My assumption is that `{{ url('/') }}` command in blade templates gives the server IP ? 
So in domain (production) environment it works well outputting: `"https://example.com"`.

But in local environment running under browsersync, all links created by laravel by `{{ url('/') }}` command will output vagrant IP address `192.168.10.30`. Once clicked on the link, the browsersync is obviously gone.

How to force laravel to output `http://localhost:3000` in place of `192.168.10.30` in local environment only?

I tried to change proxy and host in browserync config. No luck.

Also added this script to main layout php files:

```
    <script id="__bs_script__">
        // <![CDATA[
        document.write(
            "<script async src='http://HOST:PORT/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.23.6'><\/script>".replace(
                "HOST", location.hostname).replace("PORT", location.port));
        //]]>
    </script>
```

No luck either.

Browsersync config:

```
   proxy: '192.168.10.30',
   open: false,
   notify: true,
```

Host file:

```
192.168.10.30 mytest.test
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use most primitive method. Open vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php file and look for getHttpHost function.

Instead returning 
`$this->getHost().':'.$port;` write what ever you want.

Comment: Never ever edit any files in your vendor folder.

Answer (score -1):

when trying to serve the application instead of serving it directly use this instead

```
php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3000
```

Comment: he is using browserSync, another dev server, that is listening on the localhost:3000 and is listening to the artisan serve php server. Does need to be another port